# Does clipboard.js support copying anchor text?

Tags: clipboard.js

We are looking for a solution to having single-click copy to clipboard of anchor text + link that will work across chrome, safari, and IE, hopefully firefox as well.

Answer (score 1):

Clipboard.js creator here. You can definitely do that using Clipboard.js but `execCommand` (which is the API we use) is not supported in the current version of Safari. Fortunately this is going to change in Safari 10: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_10_0.html

Comment: May I know how it's done in today's Chrome? Can't seem to do it w/ the help of this library's documentation.